# On upgrade to swift3, getting an error 'cannot override a property with type GKEntity'

Tags: swift, entity, gameplay-kit

After updating to swift3, the commented line is returning an error:
    Property 'entity' with type 'GKEntity!' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional') cannot override a property with type 'GKEntity?'

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
class EntityNode: SKNode {  
    weak var entity: GKEntity!    // error here
}
```

It worked fine before the upgrade.  Any idea what is wrong and how to address this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SKNode` already has a property called `entity` which is defined like so:

```
var entity: GKEntity?
```

Therefore you can not override that with your `entity` of type `GKEntity!`

So, you can either rename your `entity` to something else, or you can use the `entity` which already exists.

You can read more about `SKNode` [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode)

Hope that helps you :)

Comment: Thanks.  This property is new since iOS 10. Having looked at the syntax used by Apple, 'https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1640688-entity', it's almost identical. I think the idea of linking GKEntities with SKNodes like this was originally found in DemoBots but I'm not sure. The question now if I can just close down my declaration and rely on the new one from Apple or if I still need some syntax changes elsewhere. Have you seen any examples with the new property?

Comment: Ah..that explains why things stopped working when you upgraded. I haven't seen any examples with the new property no, sorry. If your intent with "your" `entity` was more or less the same as the one from Apple, then I'd say that you should just use the one provided by Apple now. It seems to be the same type and the only difference being that the "Apple" `entity` is an optional whereas yours wasn't. Don't know if that helps you at all :)

Comment: I'll take a look! I've a couple more snags with the swift3 upgrade that I need to fix too before I can try Apple's property out. Thanks!